# UIWebView scroller object type

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uikit, scroll, uiscrollview

I need to access the scroller object of an UIWebView, so I do something like this :

```
id obj = [[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

The problem is that the object returns is not the same in SDK 3 and SDK 4.
In 4, it returns an UIScrollView object.
In 3, it returns me an UIScroller object, the problem is that this class isn't documented, so I assume it's a private one, is my guess right ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need to access the scroller object?

Comment: I need to detect when the scroll reach the bottom or the top of the webview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes UIScroller is a private class. It's probably a left-over during the 1.x→2.x API transition.

The interface of it can be found in http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UIScroller.h.

Comment: does that mean that implementing it has the likelihood to get your app rejected?